# Regex: Separate validation of different string parts not working

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to check whether an input meets a given format - using Regex.

- Characters 1 to 4 of the input need to be digits (0-9).
- Character 5 needs to be a dash (-).
- Characters 6 to 8 also need to be digits (0-9).

**Example:**
1234-567 should be ok.

I have tried the following but I am a beginner regarding Regex and could not get this to work.

Can someone help me with this and also provide some explanations around it so that I can apply it correctly next time ?

**My Code:**

```
var str = '1234-567';
var allowedChars1 = /^(.{3})[0-9]/;
var allowedChars2 = /^.{4}(.{1})[\-]/;
var allowedChars3 = /^.{5}(.{3})[0-9]/;

if( (str.match(allowedChars1)) && (str.match(allowedChars2)) && (str.match(allowedChars3)) ) {
    console.log('ok');
} else {
    console.log('error');
}
```

Many thanks in advance, 
Tom

Comment: You just need `/^\d{4}-\d{3}$/`. All details are available in the linked posts.

Comment: The thee conditns will never be true. But 3-5 range is `\d{3,5}` if that ment